# Pandas Merging 101

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

- How can I perform a (`INNER`| (`LEFT`|`RIGHT`|`FULL`) `OUTER`) `JOIN` with pandas?
- How do I add NaNs for missing rows after a merge?
- How do I get rid of NaNs after merging?
- Can I merge on the index?
- How do I merge multiple DataFrames?
- Cross join with pandas
- `merge`? `join`? `concat`? `update`? Who? What? Why?!

... and more. I've seen these recurring questions asking about various facets of the pandas merge functionality. Most of the information regarding merge and its various use cases today is fragmented across dozens of badly worded, unsearchable posts. The aim here is to collate some of the more important points for posterity.

This Q&A is meant to be the next installment in a series of helpful user guides on common pandas idioms (see [this post on pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), and [this post on concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio), which I will be touching on, later).

Please note that this post is *not* meant to be a replacement for [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), so please read that as well! Some of the examples are taken from there.

---

#### Table of Contents

<sub>For ease of access.</sub>

- [Merging basics - basic types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/4909087) (read this first)
- [Index-based joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167356/4909087)
- [Generalizing to multiple DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167327/4909087)
- [Cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699013/4909087)

Answer (score 1265, accepted):

This post aims to give readers a primer on SQL-flavored merging with Pandas, how to use it, and when not to use it.

In particular, here's what this post will go through:

- The basics - types of joins (LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER, INNER)

  - merging with different column names
  - merging with multiple columns
  - avoiding duplicate merge key column in output

What this post (and other posts by me on this thread) will not go through:

- Performance-related discussions and timings (for now). Mostly notable mentions of better alternatives, wherever appropriate.
- Handling suffixes, removing extra columns, renaming outputs, and other specific use cases. There are other (read: better) posts that deal with that, so figure it out!

> **Note**
> Most examples default to INNER JOIN operations while demonstrating various features, unless otherwise specified.
>
> Furthermore, all the DataFrames here can be copied and replicated so
> you can play with them. Also, see [this
> post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stackoverflow-into-python)
> on how to read DataFrames from your clipboard.
>
> Lastly, all visual representation of JOIN operations have been hand-drawn using Google Drawings. Inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858991/4909087).

---

---

## Enough talk - just show me how to use `merge`!

#### Setup & Basics

```
np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})

left

  key     value
0   A  1.764052
1   B  0.400157
2   C  0.978738
3   D  2.240893

right

  key     value
0   B  1.867558
1   D -0.977278
2   E  0.950088
3   F -0.151357
```

For the sake of simplicity, the key column has the same name (for now).

An **INNER JOIN** is represented by

[image]

> **Note**
> This, along with the forthcoming figures all follow this convention:
>
> - **blue** indicates rows that are present in the merge result
> - **red** indicates rows that are excluded from the result (i.e., removed)
> - **green** indicates missing values that are replaced with `NaN`s in the result

To perform an INNER JOIN, call [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the left DataFrame, specifying the right DataFrame and the join key (at the very least) as arguments.

```
left.merge(right, on='key')
# Or, if you want to be explicit
# left.merge(right, on='key', how='inner')

  key   value_x   value_y
0   B  0.400157  1.867558
1   D  2.240893 -0.977278
```

This returns only rows from `left` and `right` which share a common key (in this example, "B" and "D).

A **LEFT OUTER JOIN**, or LEFT JOIN  is represented by

[image]

This can be performed by specifying `how='left'`.

```
left.merge(right, on='key', how='left')

  key   value_x   value_y
0   A  1.764052       NaN
1   B  0.400157  1.867558
2   C  0.978738       NaN
3   D  2.240893 -0.977278
```

Carefully note the placement of NaNs here. If you specify `how='left'`, then only keys from `left` are used, and missing data from `right` is replaced by NaN.

And similarly, for a **RIGHT OUTER JOIN**, or RIGHT JOIN which is...

[image]

...specify `how='right'`:

```
left.merge(right, on='key', how='right')

  key   value_x   value_y
0   B  0.400157  1.867558
1   D  2.240893 -0.977278
2   E       NaN  0.950088
3   F       NaN -0.151357
```

Here, keys from `right` are used, and missing data from `left` is replaced by NaN.

Finally, for the **FULL OUTER JOIN**, given by

[image]

specify `how='outer'`.

```
left.merge(right, on='key', how='outer')

  key   value_x   value_y
0   A  1.764052       NaN
1   B  0.400157  1.867558
2   C  0.978738       NaN
3   D  2.240893 -0.977278
4   E       NaN  0.950088
5   F       NaN -0.151357
```

This uses the keys from both frames, and NaNs are inserted for missing rows in both.

The documentation summarizes these various merges nicely:

[image]

---

#### **Other JOINs - LEFT-Excluding, RIGHT-Excluding, and FULL-Excluding/ANTI JOINs**

If you need **LEFT-Excluding JOINs** and **RIGHT-Excluding JOINs** in two steps.

For LEFT-Excluding JOIN, represented as

[image]

Start by performing a LEFT OUTER JOIN and then filtering to rows coming from `left` only (excluding everything from the right),

```
(left.merge(right, on='key', how='left', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge == "left_only"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))

  key   value_x  value_y
0   A  1.764052      NaN
2   C  0.978738      NaN
```

Where,

```
left.merge(right, on='key', how='left', indicator=True)

  key   value_x   value_y     _merge
0   A  1.764052       NaN  left_only
1   B  0.400157  1.867558       both
2   C  0.978738       NaN  left_only
3   D  2.240893 -0.977278       both
```

And similarly, for a RIGHT-Excluding JOIN,

[image]

```
(left.merge(right, on='key', how='right', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge == "right_only"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))

  key  value_x   value_y
2   E      NaN  0.950088
3   F      NaN -0.151357
```

Lastly, if you are required to do a merge that only retains keys from the left or right, but not both (IOW, performing an **ANTI-JOIN**),

[image]

You can do this in similar fashion—

```
(left.merge(right, on='key', how='outer', indicator=True)
     .query('_merge != "both"')
     .drop('_merge', 1))

  key   value_x   value_y
0   A  1.764052       NaN
2   C  0.978738       NaN
4   E       NaN  0.950088
5   F       NaN -0.151357
```

---

#### **Different names for key columns**

If the key columns are named differently—for example, `left` has `keyLeft`, and `right` has `keyRight` instead of `key`—then you will have to specify `left_on` and `right_on` as arguments instead of `on`:

```
left2 = left.rename({'key':'keyLeft'}, axis=1)
right2 = right.rename({'key':'keyRight'}, axis=1)

left2

  keyLeft     value
0       A  1.764052
1       B  0.400157
2       C  0.978738
3       D  2.240893

right2

  keyRight     value
0        B  1.867558
1        D -0.977278
2        E  0.950088
3        F -0.151357
```

```
left2.merge(right2, left_on='keyLeft', right_on='keyRight', how='inner')

  keyLeft   value_x keyRight   value_y
0       B  0.400157        B  1.867558
1       D  2.240893        D -0.977278
```

---

#### **Avoiding duplicate key column in output**

When merging on `keyLeft` from `left` and `keyRight` from `right`, if you only want either of the `keyLeft` or `keyRight` (but not both) in the output, you can start by setting the index as a preliminary step.

```
left3 = left2.set_index('keyLeft')
left3.merge(right2, left_index=True, right_on='keyRight')

    value_x keyRight   value_y
0  0.400157        B  1.867558
1  2.240893        D -0.977278
```

Contrast this with the output of the command just before (that is, the output of `left2.merge(right2, left_on='keyLeft', right_on='keyRight', how='inner')`), you'll notice `keyLeft` is missing. You can figure out what column to keep based on which frame's index is set as the key. This may matter when, say, performing some OUTER JOIN operation.

---

#### **Merging only a single column from one of the `DataFrames`**

For example, consider

```
right3 = right.assign(newcol=np.arange(len(right)))
right3
  key     value  newcol
0   B  1.867558       0
1   D -0.977278       1
2   E  0.950088       2
3   F -0.151357       3
```

If you are required to merge only "newcol" (without any of the other columns), you can usually just subset columns before merging:

```
left.merge(right3[['key', 'newcol']], on='key')

  key     value  newcol
0   B  0.400157       0
1   D  2.240893       1
```

If you're doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN, a more performant solution would involve `map`:

```
# left['newcol'] = left['key'].map(right3.set_index('key')['newcol']))
left.assign(newcol=left['key'].map(right3.set_index('key')['newcol']))

  key     value  newcol
0   A  1.764052     NaN
1   B  0.400157     0.0
2   C  0.978738     NaN
3   D  2.240893     1.0
```

As mentioned, this is similar to, but faster than

```
left.merge(right3[['key', 'newcol']], on='key', how='left')

  key     value  newcol
0   A  1.764052     NaN
1   B  0.400157     0.0
2   C  0.978738     NaN
3   D  2.240893     1.0
```

---

#### **Merging on multiple columns**

To join on more than one column, specify a list for `on` (or `left_on` and `right_on`, as appropriate).

```
left.merge(right, on=['key1', 'key2'] ...)
```

Or, in the event the names are different,

```
left.merge(right, left_on=['lkey1', 'lkey2'], right_on=['rkey1', 'rkey2'])
```

---

#### **Other useful `merge*` operations and functions**

- Merging a DataFrame with Series on index: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762674/4909087).
- Besides `merge`, [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) and [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) are also used in certain cases to update one DataFrame with another.
- [`pd.merge_ordered`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_ordered.html) is a useful function for ordered JOINs.
- [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) (read: merge_asOf) is useful for *approximate* joins.

**This section only covers the very basics, and is designed to only whet your appetite. For more examples and cases, see the [documentation on `merge`, `join`, and `concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) as well as the links to the function specifications.**

---

---

## Continue Reading

Jump to other topics in Pandas Merging 101 to continue learning:

- [Merging basics - basic types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/4909087) <sup>*</sup>
- [Index-based joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167356/4909087)
- [Generalizing to multiple DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167327/4909087)
- [Cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699013/4909087)

<sub>*You are here.</sub>

Comment: If anyone is confused by the table of contents at the end of each post, I split up this massive answer into 4 separate ones, 3 on this question and 1 on another. The way it was setup previously made it harder to reference folks to specific topics. This allows you to bookmark separate topics easily now!

Comment: This is an awesome resource! The only question I still have is why call it merge instead of join, and join instead of merge?

Answer (score 95):

A supplemental visual view of `pd.concat([df0, df1], kwargs)`. 
Notice that, kwarg `axis=0` or `axis=1` 's meaning is not as intuitive as `df.mean()` or `df.apply(func)`

---

[image: on pd.concat([df0, df1])]

Comment: This is a nice diagram. May I ask how you produced it?

Comment: google doc's built-in "insert ==> drawing... ==> new" (as of 2019-May). But, to be clear: the only reason I used google doc for this picture  is because my notes is stored in google doc, and I would like a picture that can be modified quickly within google doc itself. Actually now you mentioned it, the google doc's drawing tool is pretty neat.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Coming from the SQL world, "vertical" join is not a join in my head, as the table's structure is always fixed. Now even think pandas should consolidate `concat` and `merge` with a direction parameter being `horizontal` or `vertical`.

Comment: @Ufos Isn't that exactly what `axis=1` and `axis=0` is?

Comment: yes, there're now `merge` and `concat` and axis and whatever. However, as @eliu shows, it's all just the same concept of *merge* with "left" and "right" and "horizontal" or "vertical". 
I, personally, have to look into the documentation every time I have to remember which "axis" is `0` and which is `1`.

Comment: if possible someone should address the `axis=0` and `axis=1` in `.mean() .apply() .dropna() .concat()`. I have to think a lot to decide for each case.

Comment: summary of the "axis" arguments use cases:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69679300/6226980

Comment: just for any really new python people, you need to use join='outer' or join='inner' in quotes (at least I did) ..... for example the top right diagram would be.... df_concatenated =pd.concat([df0, df1], join='outer', axis=0)   Thank you this diagram was really helpful, saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 79):

## Joins 101

These animations might be better to explain you visually.
Credits: [Garrick Aden-Buie tidyexplain repo](https://github.com/gadenbuie/tidyexplain)

### Inner Join

[image]

### Outer Join or Full Join

[image]

### Right Join

[image]

### Left Join

[image]

Answer (score 26):

In this answer, I will consider practical examples of:

1. [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)
2. [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge dataframes from the index of one and the column of another one.

We will be using different dataframes for each of the cases.

---

**1. [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)**

Considering the following `DataFrames` with the same column names:

- **Price2018** with size `(8784, 5)`

  ```
     Year  Month  Day  Hour  Price
  0  2018      1    1     1   6.74
  1  2018      1    1     2   4.74
  2  2018      1    1     3   3.66
  3  2018      1    1     4   2.30
  4  2018      1    1     5   2.30
  5  2018      1    1     6   2.06
  6  2018      1    1     7   2.06
  7  2018      1    1     8   2.06
  8  2018      1    1     9   2.30
  9  2018      1    1    10   2.30
  ```
- **Price2019** with size `(8760, 5)`

  ```
     Year  Month  Day  Hour  Price
  0  2019      1    1     1  66.88
  1  2019      1    1     2  66.88
  2  2019      1    1     3  66.00
  3  2019      1    1     4  63.64
  4  2019      1    1     5  58.85
  5  2019      1    1     6  55.47
  6  2019      1    1     7  56.00
  7  2019      1    1     8  61.09
  8  2019      1    1     9  61.01
  9  2019      1    1    10  61.00
  ```

One can combine them using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), by simply

```
import pandas as pd

frames = [Price2018, Price2019]

df_merged = pd.concat(frames)
```

Which results in a DataFrame with size `(17544, 5)`

If one wants to have a clear picture of what happened, it works like this

[image: How concat works]

([Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html))

---

**2. [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

In this section, we will consider a specific case: **merging the index of one dataframe and the column of another dataframe**.

Let's say one has the dataframe `Geo` with `54` columns, being one of the columns the `Date`, which is of type `datetime64[ns]`.

```
                 Date         1         2  ...        51        52        53
0 2010-01-01 00:00:00  0.565919  0.892376  ...  0.593049  0.775082  0.680621
1 2010-01-01 01:00:00  0.358960  0.531418  ...  0.734619  0.480450  0.926735
2 2010-01-01 02:00:00  0.531870  0.221768  ...  0.902369  0.027840  0.398864
3 2010-01-01 03:00:00  0.475463  0.245810  ...  0.306405  0.645762  0.541882
4 2010-01-01 04:00:00  0.954546  0.867960  ...  0.912257  0.039772  0.627696
```

And the dataframe `Price` that has one column with the price named `Price`, and the index corresponds to the dates (`Date`)

```
                     Price
Date                      
2010-01-01 00:00:00  29.10
2010-01-01 01:00:00   9.57
2010-01-01 02:00:00   0.00
2010-01-01 03:00:00   0.00
2010-01-01 04:00:00   0.00
```

In order to merge them, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as follows

```
df_merged = pd.merge(Price, Geo, left_index=True, right_on='Date')
```

where `Geo` and `Price` are the previous dataframes.

That results in the following dataframe

```
   Price                Date         1  ...        51        52        53
0  29.10 2010-01-01 00:00:00  0.565919  ...  0.593049  0.775082  0.680621
1   9.57 2010-01-01 01:00:00  0.358960  ...  0.734619  0.480450  0.926735
2   0.00 2010-01-01 02:00:00  0.531870  ...  0.902369  0.027840  0.398864
3   0.00 2010-01-01 03:00:00  0.475463  ...  0.306405  0.645762  0.541882
4   0.00 2010-01-01 04:00:00  0.954546  ...  0.912257  0.039772  0.627696
```

Answer (score 18):

This post will go through the following topics:

- Merging with index under different conditions

  - options for index-based joins: `merge`, `join`, `concat`
  - merging on indexes
  - merging on index of one, column of other
- effectively using named indexes to simplify merging syntax

<sub>[**BACK TO TOP**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/4909087)</sub>

---

---

## Index-based joins

#### TL;DR

> There are a few options, some simpler than others depending on the use
> case.
>
> 1. [**`DataFrame.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `left_index` and `right_index` (or `left_on` and `right_on` using named indexes)
>
>    - supports inner/left/right/full
>    - can only join two at a time
>    - supports column-column, index-column, index-index joins
> 2. [**`DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (join on index)
>
>    - supports inner/left (default)/right/full
>    - can join multiple DataFrames at a time
>    - supports index-index joins
> 3. [**`pd.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (joins on index)
>
>    - supports inner/full (default)
>    - can join multiple DataFrames at a time
>    - supports index-index joins

---

#### Index to index joins

**Setup & Basics**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 14])
left = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': np.random.randn(4)}, 
                    index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])    
right = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': np.random.randn(4)},  
                     index=['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
left.index.name = right.index.name = 'idxkey'

left
           value
idxkey          
A      -0.602923
B      -0.402655
C       0.302329
D      -0.524349

right
 
           value
idxkey          
B       0.543843
D       0.013135
E      -0.326498
F       1.385076
```

Typically, an **inner join on index** would look like this:

```
left.merge(right, left_index=True, right_index=True)

         value_x   value_y
idxkey                    
B      -0.402655  0.543843
D      -0.524349  0.013135
```

Other joins follow similar syntax.

**Notable Alternatives**

1. **[`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)** defaults to joins on the index. `DataFrame.join` does a LEFT OUTER JOIN by default, so `how='inner'` is necessary here.

   ```
    left.join(right, how='inner', lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')

             value_x   value_y
    idxkey                    
    B      -0.402655  0.543843
    D      -0.524349  0.013135
   ```

   Note that I needed to specify the `lsuffix` and `rsuffix` arguments since `join` would otherwise error out:

   ```
    left.join(right)
    ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['value'], dtype='object')
   ```

   Since the column names are the same. This would not be a problem if they were differently named.

   ```
    left.rename(columns={'value':'leftvalue'}).join(right, how='inner')

            leftvalue     value
    idxkey                     
    B       -0.402655  0.543843
    D       -0.524349  0.013135
   ```
2. **[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)** joins on the index and can join two or more DataFrames at once. It does a full outer join by default, so `how='inner'` is required here..

   ```
    pd.concat([left, right], axis=1, sort=False, join='inner')

               value     value
    idxkey                    
    B      -0.402655  0.543843
    D      -0.524349  0.013135
   ```

   For more information on `concat`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio/49620539#49620539).

---

#### **Index to Column joins**

To perform an inner join using index of left, column of right, you will use `DataFrame.merge` a combination of `left_index=True` and `right_on=...`.

```
right2 = right.reset_index().rename({'idxkey' : 'colkey'}, axis=1)
right2
 
  colkey     value
0      B  0.543843
1      D  0.013135
2      E -0.326498
3      F  1.385076

left.merge(right2, left_index=True, right_on='colkey')

    value_x colkey   value_y
0 -0.402655      B  0.543843
1 -0.524349      D  0.013135
```

Other joins follow a similar structure. Note that only `merge` can perform index to column joins. You can join on multiple columns, provided the number of index levels on the left equals the number of columns on the right.

`join` and `concat` are not capable of mixed merges. You will need to set the index as a pre-step using [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

---

#### Effectively using Named Index [pandas >= 0.23]

If your index is named, then from pandas >= 0.23, `DataFrame.merge` allows you to specify the index name to `on` (or `left_on` and `right_on` as necessary).

```
left.merge(right, on='idxkey')

         value_x   value_y
idxkey                    
B      -0.402655  0.543843
D      -0.524349  0.013135
```

For the previous example of merging with the index of left, column of right, you can use `left_on` with the index name of left:

```
left.merge(right2, left_on='idxkey', right_on='colkey')

    value_x colkey   value_y
0 -0.402655      B  0.543843
1 -0.524349      D  0.013135
```

---

---

## Continue Reading

Jump to other topics in Pandas Merging 101 to continue learning:

- [Merging basics - basic types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/4909087)
- [Index-based joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167356/4909087)<sup>*</sup>
- [Generalizing to multiple DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167327/4909087)
- [Cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699013/4909087)

<sub>* you are here</sub>

Answer (score 16):

This post will go through the following topics:

- how to correctly generalize to multiple DataFrames (and why `merge` has shortcomings here)
- merging on unique keys
- merging on non-unique keys

<sub>[**BACK TO TOP**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/4909087)</sub>

---

---

## Generalizing to multiple DataFrames

Oftentimes, the situation arises when multiple DataFrames are to be merged together. Naively, this can be done by chaining `merge` calls:

```
df1.merge(df2, ...).merge(df3, ...)
```

However, this quickly gets out of hand for many DataFrames. Furthermore, it may be necessary to generalise for an unknown number of DataFrames.

Here I introduce `pd.concat` for multi-way joins on *unique* keys, and `DataFrame.join` for multi-way joins on *non-unique* keys. First, the setup.

```
# Setup.
np.random.seed(0)
A = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'valueA': np.random.randn(4)})    
B = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'valueB': np.random.randn(4)})
C = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['D', 'E', 'J', 'C'], 'valueC': np.ones(4)})
dfs = [A, B, C] 

# Note: the "key" column values are unique, so the index is unique.
A2 = A.set_index('key')
B2 = B.set_index('key')
C2 = C.set_index('key')

dfs2 = [A2, B2, C2]
```

---

#### **Multiway merge on unique keys**

If your keys (here, the key could either be a column or an index) are unique, then you can use `pd.concat`. Note that **`pd.concat` joins DataFrames on the index**.

```
# Merge on `key` column. You'll need to set the index before concatenating
pd.concat(
    [df.set_index('key') for df in dfs], axis=1, join='inner'
).reset_index()

  key    valueA    valueB  valueC
0   D  2.240893 -0.977278     1.0

# Merge on `key` index.
pd.concat(dfs2, axis=1, sort=False, join='inner')

       valueA    valueB  valueC
key                            
D    2.240893 -0.977278     1.0
```

Omit `join='inner'` for a FULL OUTER JOIN. Note that you cannot specify LEFT or RIGHT OUTER joins (if you need these, use `join`, described below).

---

#### **Multiway merge on keys with duplicates**

`concat` is fast, but has its shortcomings. It cannot handle duplicates.

```
A3 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'], 'valueA': np.random.randn(5)})
pd.concat([df.set_index('key') for df in [A3, B, C]], axis=1, join='inner')
```

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 4), indices imply (3, 2)
```

In this situation, we can use `join` since it can handle non-unique keys (note that `join` joins DataFrames on their index; it calls `merge` under the hood and does a LEFT OUTER JOIN unless otherwise specified).

```
# Join on `key` column. Set as the index first.
# For inner join. For left join, omit the "how" argument.
A.set_index('key').join([B2, C2], how='inner').reset_index()

  key    valueA    valueB  valueC
0   D  2.240893 -0.977278     1.0

# Join on `key` index.
A3.set_index('key').join([B2, C2], how='inner')

       valueA    valueB  valueC
key                            
D    1.454274 -0.977278     1.0
D    0.761038 -0.977278     1.0
```

---

---

## Continue Reading

Jump to other topics in Pandas Merging 101 to continue learning:

- [Merging basics - basic types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645883/4909087)
- [Index-based joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167356/4909087)
- [Generalizing to multiple DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167327/4909087) <sup>*</sup>
- [Cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699013/4909087)

<sub>* you are here</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Pandas at the moment does not support inequality joins within the merge syntax; one option is with the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - I am a contributor to this library:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

left.conditional_join(right, ('value', 'value', '>'))

   left           right
    key     value   key     value
0     A  1.764052     D -0.977278
1     A  1.764052     F -0.151357
2     A  1.764052     E  0.950088
3     B  0.400157     D -0.977278
4     B  0.400157     F -0.151357
5     C  0.978738     D -0.977278
6     C  0.978738     F -0.151357
7     C  0.978738     E  0.950088
8     D  2.240893     D -0.977278
9     D  2.240893     F -0.151357
10    D  2.240893     E  0.950088
11    D  2.240893     B  1.867558

left.conditional_join(right, ('value', 'value', '<'))

  left           right
   key     value   key     value
0    A  1.764052     B  1.867558
1    B  0.400157     E  0.950088
2    B  0.400157     B  1.867558
3    C  0.978738     B  1.867558
```

The columns are passed as a variable argument of tuples, each tuple comprising of a column from the left dataframe, column from the right dataframe, and the join operator, which can be any of `(>, <, >=, <=, !=)`. In the example above, a MultiIndex column is returned, because of overlaps in the column names.

Performance wise, this is better than a naive cross join:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
dd = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randint(100000, size=50_000)})
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':np.random.randint(100000, size=1_000), 
                   'end':np.random.randint(100000, size=1_000)})

dd.head()

   value
0  68268
1  43567
2  42613
3  45891
4  21243

df.head()

   start    end
0  71915  47005
1  64284  44913
2  13377  96626
3  75823  38673
4  29151    575


%%timeit
out = df.merge(dd, how='cross')
out.loc[(out.start < out.value) & (out.end > out.value)]
5.12 s ± 19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.conditional_join(dd, ('start', 'value' ,'<'), ('end', 'value' ,'>'))
280 ms ± 5.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.conditional_join(dd, ('start', 'value' ,'<'), ('end', 'value' ,'>'), use_numba=True)
124 ms ± 12.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

out = df.merge(dd, how='cross')
out = out.loc[(out.start < out.value) & (out.end > out.value)]
A = df.conditional_join(dd, ('start', 'value' ,'<'), ('end', 'value' ,'>'))
columns = A.columns.tolist()
A = A.sort_values(columns, ignore_index = True)
out = out.sort_values(columns, ignore_index = True)

A.equals(out)
True
```

Depending on the data size, you could get more performance when an equi join is present. In this case, pandas merge function is used, but the final data frame is delayed until the non-equi joins are computed. Let's look at data from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/when-pandas-is-not-enough-use-pandasql-d762b9b84b38):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import datetime

def random_dt_bw(start_date,end_date):
    days_between = (end_date - start_date).days
    random_num_days = random.randrange(days_between)
    random_dt = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=random_num_days)
    return random_dt

def generate_data(n=1000):
    items = [f"i_{x}" for x in range(n)]
    start_dates = [random_dt_bw(datetime.date(2020,1,1),datetime.date(2020,9,1)) for x in range(n)]
    end_dates = [x + datetime.timedelta(days=random.randint(1,10)) for x in start_dates]
    
    offerDf = pd.DataFrame({"Item":items,
                            "StartDt":start_dates,
                            "EndDt":end_dates})
    
    transaction_items = [f"i_{random.randint(0,n)}" for x in range(5*n)]
    transaction_dt = [random_dt_bw(datetime.date(2020,1,1),datetime.date(2020,9,1)) for x in range(5*n)]
    sales_amt = [random.randint(0,1000) for x in range(5*n)]
    
    transactionDf = pd.DataFrame({"Item":transaction_items,"TransactionDt":transaction_dt,"Sales":sales_amt})

    return offerDf,transactionDf

offerDf,transactionDf = generate_data(n=100000)


offerDf = (offerDf
           .assign(StartDt = offerDf.StartDt.astype(np.datetime64), 
                   EndDt = offerDf.EndDt.astype(np.datetime64)
                  )
           )

transactionDf = transactionDf.assign(TransactionDt = transactionDf.TransactionDt.astype(np.datetime64))

# you can get more performance when using ints/datetimes
# in the equi join, compared to strings

offerDf = offerDf.assign(Itemr = offerDf.Item.str[2:].astype(int))

transactionDf = transactionDf.assign(Itemr = transactionDf.Item.str[2:].astype(int))

transactionDf.head()
      Item TransactionDt  Sales  Itemr
0  i_43407    2020-05-29    692  43407
1  i_95044    2020-07-22    964  95044
2  i_94560    2020-01-09    462  94560
3  i_11246    2020-02-26    690  11246
4  i_55974    2020-03-07    219  55974

offerDf.head()
  Item    StartDt      EndDt  Itemr
0  i_0 2020-04-18 2020-04-19      0
1  i_1 2020-02-28 2020-03-07      1
2  i_2 2020-03-28 2020-03-30      2
3  i_3 2020-08-03 2020-08-13      3
4  i_4 2020-05-26 2020-06-04      4

# merge on strings 
merged_df = pd.merge(offerDf,transactionDf,on='Itemr')
classic_int = merged_df[(merged_df['TransactionDt']>=merged_df['StartDt']) &
                        (merged_df['TransactionDt']<=merged_df['EndDt'])]

# merge on ints ... usually faster
merged_df = pd.merge(offerDf,transactionDf,on='Item')
classic_str = merged_df[(merged_df['TransactionDt']>=merged_df['StartDt']) &            
                        (merged_df['TransactionDt']<=merged_df['EndDt'])]

# merge on integers
cond_join_int = (transactionDf
                 .conditional_join(
                     offerDf, 
                     ('Itemr', 'Itemr', '=='), 
                     ('TransactionDt', 'StartDt', '>='), 
                     ('TransactionDt', 'EndDt', '<=')
                  )
                 )

# merge on strings
cond_join_str = (transactionDf
                 .conditional_join(
                     offerDf, 
                     ('Item', 'Item', '=='), 
                     ('TransactionDt', 'StartDt', '>='), 
                     ('TransactionDt', 'EndDt', '<=')
                  )
                )

%%timeit
merged_df = pd.merge(offerDf,transactionDf,on='Item')
classic_str = merged_df[(merged_df['TransactionDt']>=merged_df['StartDt']) &
                        (merged_df['TransactionDt']<=merged_df['EndDt'])]
292 ms ± 3.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
merged_df = pd.merge(offerDf,transactionDf,on='Itemr')
classic_int = merged_df[(merged_df['TransactionDt']>=merged_df['StartDt']) &
                        (merged_df['TransactionDt']<=merged_df['EndDt'])]
253 ms ± 2.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit 
(transactionDf
.conditional_join(
    offerDf, 
    ('Item', 'Item', '=='), 
    ('TransactionDt', 'StartDt', '>='), 
    ('TransactionDt', 'EndDt', '<=')
   )
)
256 ms ± 9.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit 
(transactionDf
.conditional_join(
    offerDf, 
    ('Itemr', 'Itemr', '=='), 
    ('TransactionDt', 'StartDt', '>='), 
    ('TransactionDt', 'EndDt', '<=')
   )
)
71.8 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# check that both dataframes are equal
cols = ['Item', 'TransactionDt', 'Sales', 'Itemr_y','StartDt', 'EndDt', 'Itemr_x']
cond_join_str = cond_join_str.drop(columns=('right', 'Item')).set_axis(cols, axis=1)

(cond_join_str
.sort_values(cond_join_str.columns.tolist())
.reset_index(drop=True)
.reindex(columns=classic_str.columns)
.equals(
    classic_str
    .sort_values(classic_str.columns.tolist())
    .reset_index(drop=True)
))

True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include this in your explanation as it is a relevant merge that I see fairly often, which is termed `cross-join` I believe. This is a merge that occurs when unique df's share no columns, and it simply merging 2 dfs side-by-side:

The setup:

```
names1 = [{'A':'Jack', 'B':'Jill'}]

names2 = [{'C':'Tommy', 'D':'Tammy'}]

df1=pd.DataFrame(names1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(names2)
df_merged= pd.merge(df1.assign(X=1), df2.assign(X=1), on='X').drop('X', 1)
```

This creates a dummy X column, merges on the X, and then drops it to produce

df_merged:

```
      A     B      C      D
0  Jack  Jill  Tommy  Tammy
```

Comment: Please check the second comment under the question. Cross join was initially a part of this (see edit history) but was later edited out into it's own post for volume.

Comment: Seeing as cross join was not meant to be covered here, yes... However I appreciate your intent to contribute in good faith :)